# Is it possible to inherit a parent scope member property and assign it to a inner variable in the "use" statement?

Tags: php, syntax, closures, scoping

The following works (also with objects etc.):

```
$b = new stdClass();

$b->a = "foo";
$b->b = "bar";

$example = function () use ($b) {
    echo $b->b;
};
$example();
```

Is there some syntax trick for passing some object property/array member and assigning it to a new variable at the same time without defining this variable in the outer scope?

This *pseudo-code* example should demonstrate what I  mean:

```
$b = new stdClass();

$b->a = "foo";
$b->b = "bar";

$example = function () use ($b->b as $prop) {
    echo $prop;
};
$example();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just define it as a parameter and be done with it? What you are trying to do is exactly what functions do normally.

E.g. and following exactly the use case you present in your question:

```php
$example = function ($prop) {
    echo $prop;
};

$example($b->b);
```

Of course, if you want to modify the variable, you just need to declare it as passing by reference:

```php
$anotherExample = function (&$prop) {
    echo $prop;
};
```

`use` doesn't do what you want to do, nor it makes much sense that it would. Simply passing parameters to a function, which is in the basic nature of functions, solves this "issue".

Comment: Very well stated

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to taking that action inside the closure's 'use' clause statement, I believe the answer is no. All the 'use' clause does is give your closure access to (a) variable(s) that already reside(s) within the parent scope.

If you want to modify the actual value of the variable you're including via 'use', you can pass it by reference to modify the original value in the outer scope, but to the best of my knowledge there is no assignment allowed inside of that 'use' clause statement that would allow you to create a new variable accessible within the closure scope that has the value of the original variable in outer scope.